# Rails "students exam" app , improving performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I read several questions and installed Bullet gem to avoid N+1 problems but still no luck.I'm using Postgre

I'm developing an exams app, Classes are :

- Instrument (the evaluation)
- Question
- Ability ( question attribute, I have more but behaviour is the same)
- Content (another attribute)
- Alternative
- Answer (stores student and alternative chosen)
- Guide (stores question + correct alternative)
- Student

I need to generate reports with, for example, the success of the class grouping by Ability , Content, a list of each Student with it success , etc ..

I'm actually managing this by the controller with code like this :

**building a table with Abilities included in one evaluation, amount of questions, and % of success of the class on each Ability**

```
def habilidad_pme
  @pme_abilities = @instrument.evaluation.questions.map{|q| q.pme_ability }.uniq
  @pme_table = []
  @pme_abilities.each do |pmea|
    nombre_pmea = pmea.nombre
    cantidad_preguntas = @instrument.evaluation.questions.map{|q| q if q.pme_ability_id == pmea.id  }.compact.count
    ccpme = cantidad_correctas_pme(pmea)
    porcentaje = @asistencia > 0 ? (ccpme/(cantidad_preguntas*@asistencia.to_f)*100).to_i : 0
    @pme_table << { nombre_pme: nombre_pmea, cantidad_preguntas: cantidad_preguntas, porcentaje: porcentaje }
  end
  @pme_table
end



def cantidad_correctas_pme(pme)
  preg = @instrument.evaluation.questions.map{|q| q if q.pme_ability_id == pme.id  }.compact
  correctas = 0
  preg.each do |p|
    Answer.where(question_id: p.id, proccess_instrument: @proccess_instrument).each do |a|
      if a.letra == @instrument.guides.find_by(question_id: p.id).alternative_index
        correctas+=1
      end
    end
  end
  correctas
end
```

**amount of right answers of each question**

```
def cantidad_correctas(question)
  correctas = 0
  Answer.where(question_id: question.id, proccess_instrument: @proccess_instrument).each do |a|
    if a.letra == @instrument.guides.find_by(question_id: question.id).alternative_index
      correctas+=1
    end
  end
  correctas
end
```

**amount of right answers of questions grouped by Ability-Content**

```
def habilidad_contenido_pme
  @pmes = @instrument.evaluation.questions.map{ |q| q.pme_ability }.uniq
  @pme_content_table = []
  @pmes.each do |pm|
    pme_parcial = []
    preguntas_pme = @instrument.evaluation.questions.where(:pme_ability_id => pm.id).joins(:content).group('contents.id').count
    preguntas_pme.each do |key,value| 
      contenido = Content.find(key.to_i)
      cc = cantidad_correctas_pme_contenido(pm,contenido)
      porcentaje = @asistencia > 0 ? (cc/(value*@asistencia.to_f)*100).to_i : 0
      pme_parcial << {nombre_pme: pm.nombre, nombre_contenido: contenido.nombre, cantidad_preguntas: value, porcentaje: porcentaje }
    end
    @pme_content_table << pme_parcial
  end
  @pme_content_table
end

def cantidad_correctas_pme_contenido(pme,content)
  preg = @instrument.evaluation.questions.map{|q| q if q.pme_ability_id == pme.id && q.content_id == content.id }.compact
  correctas = 0
  preg.each do |p|
    Answer.where(question_id: p.id, proccess_instrument: @proccess_instrument).each do |a|
      if a.letra == @instrument.guides.find_by(question_id: p.id).alternative_index
        correctas+=1
      end
    end
  end
  correctas
end
```

Works, but its very slow in my opinion, I have to use methods like this about 10 times per report (using different question attributes) , a class has 30 students, and each student answers about 30 questions.

Generating 1 report takes about 40seconds-1 minute , rails log gets crazy every time I generate a report, the amount of queries is huge.

I think the solution here is to use 1 big query per table, but I cant find a way to start.

regards

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktZLpjCanvg

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume how the models (relationships) look like, so you might need to tweak the following to work. There could have been a more optimised solution than this, but I prefer not to change your implementation.

```
def habilidad_pme
  @pme_abilities = PmeAbility.includes(question: {evaluation: :instrument}).where(instruments: {id: @instrument.id})
  @pme_table = []
  @pme_abilities.find_each do |pmea|
    nombre_pmea = pmea.nombre
    cantidad_preguntas = @instrument.evaluation.questions.where(pme_ability_id: pmea.id).count
    ccpme = cantidad_correctas_pme(pmea)
    porcentaje = @asistencia > 0 ? (ccpme/(cantidad_preguntas*@asistencia.to_f)*100).to_i : 0
    @pme_table << { nombre_pme: nombre_pmea, cantidad_preguntas: cantidad_preguntas, porcentaje: porcentaje }
  end
  @pme_table
end

def cantidad_correctas_pme(pme)
  preg = @instrument.evaluation.questions.where(pme_ability_id: pme.id)
  correctas = 0
  preg.find_each do |p|
    correctas += Answer.where(question_id: p.id, proccess_instrument: @proccess_instrument, letra: @instrument.guides.find_by(question_id: p.id).alternative_index).count
  end
  correctas
end
```

Using this as a reference, you should now be able to optimise the others as well.

Comment: I'm getting error with habilidad_pme, my fault was to not specify relations :

PmeAbility
has_many :questions
Question
belongs_to :pme_ability
belongs_to :content
Answer
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :student
Instrument
belongs_to :evaluation
has_many :guides
Guide
belongs_to :instrument
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :alternative

Comment: What was the error? Does your `Question has_many :evaluations` ? It is a little hard following your question. If it takes a long time for me to respond, you could manually just change this part `.includes(...)` (line 2) from my code. Make them plural or singular depending on the associations. For example since you said `PmeAbility has_many  :questions`, then I will have to update my answer in the 2nd line to be `@pme_abilities = PmeAbility.includes(questions: ...)` However for the `.where()` method, it should always be plural (same as the table name)